# Difference between IDE and SATA DVD writers

Tags: sata, comparison, optical-drive, pata

What is the difference between IDE and SATA type DVD writers? My motherboard supports both. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend definitely to choose SATA for all new products you can buy. Motherboards still support IDE today, but I suppose that within a couple of years manufacturers will start removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rodeey said, there isn't much a difference feature-wise.

The advantage of SATA is the thinner cable, so it is easier to route the cable in a cramped case. The cable can also be longer than IDE cables, so you can move the DVD drive to the upper drive bay of a big tower case.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this page](http://gadgetophilia.com/sata-pata-and-scsi-a-comparison/) to see features of SATA, IDE/PATA and SCSI technologies. There is also a thorough comparison.

[image]

Comment: That chart's slightly dated.  Sata6 is out now and has a 600MB/sec bus speed.

Comment: And this describes the max theoretical speeds. Nothing of importance for DVD writers that do not approach them.

Comment: @Dan Neely: To correct; it's not Sata6, it's SATA III (Third generation - 600 MB/sec) which is the only missing component of the chart. Chart date:  May 13, 2009.

Answer (score 2):

Short of the bus type (IDE vs SATA), there isn't much a difference to you. As long as your burning software supports SATA drives then that's what you should get.

Comment: FYI: IDE is rapidly becoming a legacy format.  It's being replaced by SATA on modern motherboards.  I expect most motherboards to support both for some time but eventually IDE will go the way of ATA.